# Sticky Navbar scrolls away when scrolling within main element

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, sticky

So I really don't know what to do right now, if I scroll just below the hero section the navbar stays put, but as soon as I scroll further down the navbar suddenly scrolls away despite it's 'sticky' and 'top-0' tag.

I've tried to change padding and margins but that didnt' help.
The website is on https://wingetty.dev and a Tailwind playground here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>WinGetty - Private Winget Repos made easy</title>
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>


  <script>
    // On page load or when changing themes, best to add inline in `head` to avoid FOUC
    if (localStorage.getItem('color-theme') === 'dark' || (!('color-theme' in localStorage) && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches)) {
      document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
    } else {
      document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark')
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body class="min-h-screen h-screen  flex flex-col bg-white dark:bg-neutral-950 font-poppins">
  <nav class="shadow-xl shadow-blue-500/20 sticky top-0 left-0 h-auto z-50 backdrop-blur-xl ">
    <div
      class="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap  text-neutral-700 dark:text-neutral-100    p-4 max-w-screen-2xl mx-auto">
      <div class="flex flex-row items-center flex-shrink-0 text-neutral-900 dark:text-neutral-200 mr-6">
        <img src="img/wingetty.png" alt="Logo" class="h-10 mr-2">
        <span class="font-semibold text-2xl tracking-tight mb-0.5">WinGetty</span>
      </div>
      <div class="block lg:hidden">
        <button class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 border rounded  border-blue-400 hover:text-white hover:border-white">
          <svg class="fill-current h-3 w-3" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <title>Menu</title>
            <path d="M0 3h20v2H0V3zm0 6h20v2H0V9zm0 6h20v2H0v-2z" />
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="w-full block flex-grow  lg:flex lg:items-center lg:w-auto">
        <div class="text-lg font-semibold">
          <a href="{{ url_for('ui.packages') }}"
            class="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0  hover:text-blue-600 mr-4 transition-colors duration-500">
            Home
          </a>

          <a href="{{ url_for('ui.packages') }}"
            class="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0  hover:text-blue-600 mr-4 transition-colors duration-500">
            Pricing
          </a>



        </div>

        <div class="text-lg font-semibold self-end ml-auto flex flex-row items-center">
          <a href="{{ url_for('ui.packages') }}"
            class="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0  hover:text-blue-600 mr-4 transition-colors duration-500">
            About
          </a>
          <a href="{{ url_for('ui.setup') }}"
            class="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0  hover:text-blue-600 mr-4 transition-colors duration-500">
            Login
          </a>
          <button id="theme-toggle" class="theme-toggle" type="button" title="Toggle theme" aria-label="Toggle theme">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" width="1.2em" height="1.2em" fill="currentColor"
              class="theme-toggle__expand" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
              <clipPath id="theme-toggle__expand__cutout">
                <path d="M0-11h25a1 1 0 0017 13v30H0Z" />
              </clipPath>
              <g clip-path="url(#theme-toggle__expand__cutout)">
                <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="8.4" />
                <path
                  d="M18.3 3.2c0 1.3-1 2.3-2.3 2.3s-2.3-1-2.3-2.3S14.7.9 16 .9s2.3 1 2.3 2.3zm-4.6 25.6c0-1.3 1-2.3 2.3-2.3s2.3 1 2.3 2.3-1 2.3-2.3 2.3-2.3-1-2.3-2.3zm15.1-10.5c-1.3 0-2.3-1-2.3-2.3s1-2.3 2.3-2.3 2.3 1 2.3 2.3-1 2.3-2.3 2.3zM3.2 13.7c1.3 0 2.3 1 2.3 2.3s-1 2.3-2.3 2.3S.9 17.3.9 16s1-2.3 2.3-2.3zm5.8-7C9 7.9 7.9 9 6.7 9S4.4 8 4.4 6.7s1-2.3 2.3-2.3S9 5.4 9 6.7zm16.3 21c-1.3 0-2.3-1-2.3-2.3s1-2.3 2.3-2.3 2.3 1 2.3 2.3-1 2.3-2.3 2.3zm2.4-21c0 1.3-1 2.3-2.3 2.3S23 7.9 23 6.7s1-2.3 2.3-2.3 2.4 1 2.4 2.3zM6.7 23C8 23 9 24 9 25.3s-1 2.3-2.3 2.3-2.3-1-2.3-2.3 1-2.3 2.3-2.3z" />
              </g>
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <main class="min-h-screen w-full flex flex-col">
    <section class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800">
      <div class="grid max-w-screen-2xl px-4 py-8 mx-auto lg:gap-8 xl:gap-0 lg:py-16 lg:grid-cols-12">
        <div class="mr-auto place-self-center lg:col-span-4">
          <div
            class="max-w-2xl mb-4 text-4xl font-extrabold tracking-tight leading-none md:text-5xl xl:text-6xl dark:text-white">
            <h1 class="">
              WinGetty</h1>
            <div class="text-2xl md:text-3xl xl:text-4xl font-medium flex flex-col mt-3">
              <h3>Private WinGet Repositories</h3>
              <h3>made <span
                  class="text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-r from-sky-500 to-indigo-500 font-bold pr-1">easy</span>
              </h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--
          <p class="max-w-2xl mb-6 text-gray-500 lg:mb-8 md:text-lg lg:text-xl dark:text-gray-400">
            With WinGetty, you can start distributing your own packages within minutes and manage everything through an
            intuitive user interface.<br>
            <span class="font-medium">No Azure required.</span>
          </p>-->
          <a href="#"
            class="inline-flex items-center justify-center px-5 py-3 mr-3 text-base font-medium text-center text-white rounded-lg transition-colors duration-300 bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-700 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 dark:focus:ring-blue-900">
            Try out the beta
            <svg class="w-5 h-5 ml-2 -mr-1" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                d="M10.293 3.293a1 1 0 011.414 0l6 6a1 1 0 010 1.414l-6 6a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L14.586 11H3a1 1 0 110-2h11.586l-4.293-4.293a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
                clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
            </svg>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="order-first lg:order-none mb-8 lg:mb-0 lg:mt-0 lg:col-span-8 lg:flex relative">
          <img class="object-contain hidden  dark:block hero_image" src="https://wingetty.sirv.com/Images/tiles.png?profile=Hero" alt="mockup">
          <img class="object-contain block dark:hidden hero_image" src="https://wingetty.sirv.com/Images/tiles_light.png?profile=Hero" alt="mockup">

        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="bg-gray-100 dark:bg-neutral-900 ">
      <div class="py-8 px-4 mx-auto max-w-screen-xl sm:py-16 lg:px-6 ">
        <div class=" mb-8 lg:mb-16 w-full max-w-screen-md mx-auto">
          <h2 class="mb-4 text-4xl tracking-tight font-extrabold text-gray-900 dark:text-white text-center">Made for <span
              class="text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-r from-sky-400 to-blue-500 font-black">everyone</span>
          </h2>
          <p class="text-gray-500 sm:text-xl dark:text-gray-400 text-center">Whether you are a developer, a system
            administrator or just getting started with WinGet, WinGetty is the perfect solution for you.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="space-y-8 md:grid md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 md:gap-12 md:space-y-0">
          <div class="flex flex-col items-center">


            <svg class="w-14 h-14 text-blue-600 lg:w-16 lg:h-16" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true">
              <path
                d="M12 .75a8.25 8.25 0 00-4.135 15.39c.686.398 1.115 1.008 1.134 1.623a.75.75 0 00.577.706c.352.083.71.148 1.074.195.323.041.6-.218.6-.544v-4.661a6.714 6.714 0 01-.937-.171.75.75 0 11.374-1.453 5.261 5.261 0 002.626 0 .75.75 0 11.374 1.452 6.712 6.712 0 01-.937.172v4.66c0 .327.277.586.6.545.364-.047.722-.112 1.074-.195a.75.75 0 00.577-.706c.02-.615.448-1.225 1.134-1.623A8.25 8.25 0 0012 .75z">
              </path>
              <path clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd"
                d="M9.013 19.9a.75.75 0 01.877-.597 11.319 11.319 0 004.22 0 .75.75 0 11.28 1.473 12.819 12.819 0 01-4.78 0 .75.75 0 01-.597-.876zM9.754 22.344a.75.75 0 01.824-.668 13.682 13.682 0 002.844 0 .75.75 0 11.156 1.492 15.156 15.156 0 01-3.156 0 .75.75 0 01-.668-.824z">
              </path>
            </svg>

            <h3 class="my-2 text-xl font-bold dark:text-white">Easy to use</h3>
            <p class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 text-center">
              With it's intuitive user interface you can add packages, add versions and installers and get started
              distributing your own packages within minutes.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
            <svg class="w-14 h-14 text-blue-600 lg:w-16 lg:h-16 " fill="currentColor"
              viewBox="0 -3.5 256 256" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
              <g>
                <path
                  d="M127.505 0C57.095 0 0 57.085 0 127.505c0 56.336 36.534 104.13 87.196 120.99 6.372 1.18 8.712-2.766 8.712-6.134 0-3.04-.119-13.085-.173-23.739-35.473 7.713-42.958-15.044-42.958-15.044-5.8-14.738-14.157-18.656-14.157-18.656-11.568-7.914.872-7.752.872-7.752 12.804.9 19.546 13.14 19.546 13.14 11.372 19.493 29.828 13.857 37.104 10.6 1.144-8.242 4.449-13.866 8.095-17.05-28.32-3.225-58.092-14.158-58.092-63.014 0-13.92 4.981-25.295 13.138-34.224-1.324-3.212-5.688-16.18 1.235-33.743 0 0 10.707-3.427 35.073 13.07 10.17-2.826 21.078-4.242 31.914-4.29 10.836.048 21.752 1.464 31.942 4.29 24.337-16.497 35.029-13.07 35.029-13.07 6.94 17.563 2.574 30.531 1.25 33.743 8.175 8.929 13.122 20.303 13.122 34.224 0 48.972-29.828 59.756-58.22 62.912 4.573 3.957 8.648 11.717 8.648 23.612 0 17.06-.148 30.791-.148 34.991 0 3.393 2.295 7.369 8.759 6.117 50.634-16.879 87.122-64.656 87.122-120.973C255.009 57.085 197.922 0 127.505 0" />
                <path
                  d="M47.755 181.634c-.28.633-1.278.823-2.185.389-.925-.416-1.445-1.28-1.145-1.916.275-.652 1.273-.834 2.196-.396.927.415 1.455 1.287 1.134 1.923M54.027 187.23c-.608.564-1.797.302-2.604-.589-.834-.889-.99-2.077-.373-2.65.627-.563 1.78-.3 2.616.59.834.899.996 2.08.36 2.65M58.33 194.39c-.782.543-2.06.034-2.849-1.1-.781-1.133-.781-2.493.017-3.038.792-.545 2.05-.055 2.85 1.07.78 1.153.78 2.513-.019 3.069M65.606 202.683c-.699.77-2.187.564-3.277-.488-1.114-1.028-1.425-2.487-.724-3.258.707-.772 2.204-.555 3.302.488 1.107 1.026 1.445 2.496.7 3.258M75.01 205.483c-.307.998-1.741 1.452-3.185 1.028-1.442-.437-2.386-1.607-2.095-2.616.3-1.005 1.74-1.478 3.195-1.024 1.44.435 2.386 1.596 2.086 2.612M85.714 206.67c.036 1.052-1.189 1.924-2.705 1.943-1.525.033-2.758-.818-2.774-1.852 0-1.062 1.197-1.926 2.721-1.951 1.516-.03 2.758.815 2.758 1.86M96.228 206.267c.182 1.026-.872 2.08-2.377 2.36-1.48.27-2.85-.363-3.039-1.38-.184-1.052.89-2.105 2.367-2.378 1.508-.262 2.857.355 3.049 1.398" />
              </g>
            </svg>
            <h3 class="my-2 text-xl font-bold dark:text-white">Open Source</h3>
            <p class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 text-center">
              WinGetty is open source and free to use. The source code is available on GitHub and you can contribute to
              the project if you want to.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
            <svg class="w-14 h-14 text-blue-600 lg:w-16 lg:h-16 " fill="currentColor"
              viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                d="M6 6V5a3 3 0 013-3h2a3 3 0 013 3v1h2a2 2 0 012 2v3.57A22.952 22.952 0 0110 13a22.95 22.95 0 01-8-1.43V8a2 2 0 012-2h2zm2-1a1 1 0 011-1h2a1 1 0 011 1v1H8V5zm1 5a1 1 0 011-1h.01a1 1 0 110 2H10a1 1 0 01-1-1z"
                clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
              <path
                d="M2 13.692V16a2 2 0 002 2h12a2 2 0 002-2v-2.308A24.974 24.974 0 0110 15c-2.796 0-5.487-.46-8-1.308z">
              </path>
            </svg>
            <h3 class="my-2 text-xl font-bold dark:text-white">Fully private</h3>
            <p class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 text-center">
              WinGetty is fully private and does not require any Azure services allowing you to keep your packages and
              data on your own servers and under your control.

            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800">
      <div class="py-8 px-4 mx-auto max-w-screen-xl sm:py-16 lg:px-6 ">
        <div class=" mb-8 lg:mb-16 w-full max-w-screen-md mx-auto">
          <h2 class="mb-4 text-4xl tracking-tight font-extrabold text-gray-900 dark:text-white text-center">Easy as <span
              class="text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-r from-sky-400 to-blue-500 font-black">
              1. 2. 3.
            </span>
          </h2>
          <p class="text-gray-500 sm:text-xl dark:text-gray-400 text-center">
            Just follow these three simple steps.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="space-y-8 md:grid md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 md:gap-12 md:space-y-0">
          <div class="flex flex-col items-center">


            <svg class="w-14 h-14 text-blue-600 lg:w-16 lg:h-16" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true">
              <path
                d="M12 .75a8.25 8.25 0 00-4.135 15.39c.686.398 1.115 1.008 1.134 1.623a.75.75 0 00.577.706c.352.083.71.148 1.074.195.323.041.6-.218.6-.544v-4.661a6.714 6.714 0 01-.937-.171.75.75 0 11.374-1.453 5.261 5.261 0 002.626 0 .75.75 0 11.374 1.452 6.712 6.712 0 01-.937.172v4.66c0 .327.277.586.6.545.364-.047.722-.112 1.074-.195a.75.75 0 00.577-.706c.02-.615.448-1.225 1.134-1.623A8.25 8.25 0 0012 .75z">
              </path>
              <path clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd"
                d="M9.013 19.9a.75.75 0 01.877-.597 11.319 11.319 0 004.22 0 .75.75 0 11.28 1.473 12.819 12.819 0 01-4.78 0 .75.75 0 01-.597-.876zM9.754 22.344a.75.75 0 01.824-.668 13.682 13.682 0 002.844 0 .75.75 0 11.156 1.492 15.156 15.156 0 01-3.156 0 .75.75 0 01-.668-.824z">
              </path>
            </svg>

            <h3 class="my-2 text-xl font-bold dark:text-white">Install & Host</h3>
            <p class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 text-center">
              Just clone the repository or use the Docker image, configure the settings and host it on your own server.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
            <svg class="w-14 h-14 text-blue-600 lg:w-16 lg:h-16 " fill="currentColor"
              viewBox="0 -3.5 256 256" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
              <g>
                <path
                  d="M127.505 0C57.095 0 0 57.085 0 127.505c0 56.336 36.534 104.13 87.196 120.99 6.372 1.18 8.712-2.766 8.712-6.134 0-3.04-.119-13.085-.173-23.739-35.473 7.713-42.958-15.044-42.958-15.044-5.8-14.738-14.157-18.656-14.157-18.656-11.568-7.914.872-7.752.872-7.752 12.804.9 19.546 13.14 19.546 13.14 11.372 19.493 29.828 13.857 37.104 10.6 1.144-8.242 4.449-13.866 8.095-17.05-28.32-3.225-58.092-14.158-58.092-63.014 0-13.92 4.981-25.295 13.138-34.224-1.324-3.212-5.688-16.18 1.235-33.743 0 0 10.707-3.427 35.073 13.07 10.17-2.826 21.078-4.242 31.914-4.29 10.836.048 21.752 1.464 31.942 4.29 24.337-16.497 35.029-13.07 35.029-13.07 6.94 17.563 2.574 30.531 1.25 33.743 8.175 8.929 13.122 20.303 13.122 34.224 0 48.972-29.828 59.756-58.22 62.912 4.573 3.957 8.648 11.717 8.648 23.612 0 17.06-.148 30.791-.148 34.991 0 3.393 2.295 7.369 8.759 6.117 50.634-16.879 87.122-64.656 87.122-120.973C255.009 57.085 197.922 0 127.505 0" />
                <path
                  d="M47.755 181.634c-.28.633-1.278.823-2.185.389-.925-.416-1.445-1.28-1.145-1.916.275-.652 1.273-.834 2.196-.396.927.415 1.455 1.287 1.134 1.923M54.027 187.23c-.608.564-1.797.302-2.604-.589-.834-.889-.99-2.077-.373-2.65.627-.563 1.78-.3 2.616.59.834.899.996 2.08.36 2.65M58.33 194.39c-.782.543-2.06.034-2.849-1.1-.781-1.133-.781-2.493.017-3.038.792-.545 2.05-.055 2.85 1.07.78 1.153.78 2.513-.019 3.069M65.606 202.683c-.699.77-2.187.564-3.277-.488-1.114-1.028-1.425-2.487-.724-3.258.707-.772 2.204-.555 3.302.488 1.107 1.026 1.445 2.496.7 3.258M75.01 205.483c-.307.998-1.741 1.452-3.185 1.028-1.442-.437-2.386-1.607-2.095-2.616.3-1.005 1.74-1.478 3.195-1.024 1.44.435 2.386 1.596 2.086 2.612M85.714 206.67c.036 1.052-1.189 1.924-2.705 1.943-1.525.033-2.758-.818-2.774-1.852 0-1.062 1.197-1.926 2.721-1.951 1.516-.03 2.758.815 2.758 1.86M96.228 206.267c.182 1.026-.872 2.08-2.377 2.36-1.48.27-2.85-.363-3.039-1.38-.184-1.052.89-2.105 2.367-2.378 1.508-.262 2.857.355 3.049 1.398" />
              </g>
            </svg>
            <h3 class="my-2 text-xl font-bold dark:text-white">Connect to Repository</h3>
            <p class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 text-center">
              Connect your Windows devices to your repository by running a single command.
              This is as easy as typing <span class="bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-900 rounded-sm px-1 font-mono">winget source add</span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
            <svg class="w-14 h-14 text-blue-600 lg:w-16 lg:h-16 " fill="currentColor"
              viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                d="M6 6V5a3 3 0 013-3h2a3 3 0 013 3v1h2a2 2 0 012 2v3.57A22.952 22.952 0 0110 13a22.95 22.95 0 01-8-1.43V8a2 2 0 012-2h2zm2-1a1 1 0 011-1h2a1 1 0 011 1v1H8V5zm1 5a1 1 0 011-1h.01a1 1 0 110 2H10a1 1 0 01-1-1z"
                clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
              <path
                d="M2 13.692V16a2 2 0 002 2h12a2 2 0 002-2v-2.308A24.974 24.974 0 0110 15c-2.796 0-5.487-.46-8-1.308z">
              </path>
            </svg>
            <h3 class="my-2 text-xl font-bold dark:text-white">Fully private</h3>
            <p class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 text-center">
              WinGetty is fully private and does not require any Azure services allowing you to keep your packages and
              data on your own servers and under your control.

            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

  </main>

  <script>
    var themeToggleBtn = document.getElementById('theme-toggle');

    // Change the icons inside the button based on previous settings
    if (localStorage.getItem('color-theme') === 'dark' || (!('color-theme' in localStorage) && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches)) {
      themeToggleBtn.classList.add('theme-toggle--toggled');

    } else {
      themeToggleBtn.classList.remove('theme-toggle--toggled');
    }


    themeToggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {

      themeToggleBtn.classList.toggle('theme-toggle--toggled');


      // if set via local storage previously
      if (localStorage.getItem('color-theme')) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('color-theme') === 'light') {
          document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
          localStorage.setItem('color-theme', 'dark');
        } else {
          document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark');
          localStorage.setItem('color-theme', 'light');
        }

        // if NOT set via local storage previously
      } else {
        if (document.documentElement.classList.contains('dark')) {
          document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark');
          localStorage.setItem('color-theme', 'light');
        } else {
          document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
          localStorage.setItem('color-theme', 'dark');
        }
      }

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sticky to it's wrapping container which is body, the height of body doesn't allow it to take up the whole webpage, so it will stop being sticky at the bottom of the body element.

Try giving body a height of auto or 100%

Comment: Yup, replacing h-screen in body with h-full fixed the issue. Thank you so much.